# React Front end, Django back-end, Braintree API CORS error

Tags: reactjs, django, cors, braintree

Hello I've been struggling with this issue for days now, I have built an app in react, the backend is using django and DRF, and I'm using braintree as payment platform, I'm trying to POST a form from react to django but in react I'm getting the error saying fetch fails because it was blocked by CORS, in django I get an error 400 saying bad request, and the request type is OPTIONS, I did some troubleshoot and turns out the form is been sent empty(I was reading about OPTIONS and it seems if the server does not allow the request then it turns into an empty array). I have added django-cors-headers to apps installed, middleware, allowed hosts, etc..  anyway, here's my code.

DebitCard.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as braintree from 'braintree-web'

function DebitCard() {
  const storedData = localStorage.getItem('donationData');
  const formData = storedData ? JSON.parse(storedData) : null;

  const [clientToken, setClientToken] = useState(null);
  const [client, setClient] = useState(null);
  const [hostedFieldsInstance, setHostedFieldsInstance] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchClientToken() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3001/client-token/');
        const jsonResponse = await response.json();
        const clientToken = jsonResponse.client_token;
        setClientToken(clientToken);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch client token:', err);
      }
    }
  
    fetchClientToken();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (clientToken) {
      braintree.client
        .create({ authorization:clientToken })
        .then((clientInstance) => {
          setClient(clientInstance);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('Failed to create client:', err)
        });
    }
  },[clientToken]);

  useEffect(()=> {
    if (client) {
      braintree.hostedFields
        .create({
          client: client,
          styles:{

          },
          fields:{
            number:{
              selector: '#card-number',
            },
            cvv:{
              selector: '#card-cvv',
            },
            expirationDate: {
              selector: '#card-expiry',
            },
            postalCode: {
              selector: '#zipcode',
            }
          }
        })
        .then((hostedFieldsInstance) => {
          setHostedFieldsInstance(hostedFieldsInstance)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('Failed to created hosted fields', err)
        })
    }
  }, [client]);
  


  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    const transactionData = {
      first_name: formData.firstName,
      last_name: formData.lastName,
      email: formData.email,
      phone: formData.phone,
      amount: formData.donationAmount,
      program: formData.donationType,
      billing_address: '560 Lambert Rd',
      billing_city_town: 'Brea',
      billing_state: 'California',
    };
  
    if (hostedFieldsInstance) {
      try {
        const { nonce } = await hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize();
        transactionData['payment_method_nonce'] = nonce;
  
        const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:3001/mobile-booth-donation/', transactionData, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        });
        
        console.log(response);
  
        if (!response.data.success) {
          throw new Error('Failed to submit transaction data');
        }
        
        console.log('Transaction data submitted successfully');
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Failed to tokenize hosted fields', err);
      }
    }
  };



  return (
    <div className='debit-card-payment'>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className='input-field'>
        <label htmlFor="card-number-label">Card Number:</label>
        <div id="card-number" placeholder="4444 4444 4444 4444" ></div>
      </div>
      <div className='exp-cvc-wrapper'>
      <div className='input-field'>
        <label htmlFor="card-expiry-label">Exp Date:</label>
        <div id="card-expiry" placeholder="12/24" ></div>
      </div>
        <div className='input-field'>
          <label htmlFor="card-cvv-label">CVC:</label>
          <div id="card-cvv" placeholder="123" ></div>
        </div>
        <div className='input-field'>
          <label htmlFor="zipcode-label">Zipcode:</label>
          <div id="zipcode" placeholder="123" ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Pay with Debit Card</button>
    </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DebitCard;
```

Django API

```
gateway = braintree.BraintreeGateway(
            braintree.Configuration(
                braintree.Environment.Production,
                merchant_id=settings.BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID_PRODUCTION,
                public_key=settings.BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY_PRODUCTION,
                private_key=settings.BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY_PRODUCTION

@csrf_exempt
def braintree_token(request):
    gateway = braintree_gateway(request)
    client_token = gateway.client_token.generate()
    print("Generated client token:", client_token)
    response = JsonResponse({"client_token": client_token})
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "http://localhost:3000"
    return response

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class CheckoutFormView(FormView):
    print('executing')
    template_name = 'checkout.html'
    success_url = '/checkout/thank-you/'
    http_method_names = ['post', 'get','options']
    
    def options(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.body)
        if request.body:
            try:
                print(request.body)
                print(json.loads(request.body))
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                print(f"JSONDecodeError: {e}")
                return JsonResponse({"error": "Invalid JSON"}, status=400)
        else:
            print("Empty request body")
            return JsonResponse({"error": "Empty request body"}, status=400)

        response = HttpResponse()
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type'
        return response



    def get_form_class(self):
        print('checkout type')
        if self.request.session.get('checkout_type') == 'purchase':
            self.form_class = OrderForm
        elif self.request.session.get('checkout_type') == 'subscribe':
            self.form_class = SubscribeForm
        elif self.request.session.get('checkout_type') == 'registration':
            self.form_class = RegistrationForm
        else:
            self.form_class = DonateForm
        return self.form_class

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        try:
            program = self.request.session['program']
            program = Program.objects.get(slug=program.slug)
        except:
            program = Program.objects.get(slug='where-its-needed-most')
            
        context['product'] = self.request.session.get('product', '')
        context['event'] = self.request.session.get('event', '')
        context['schedule'] = self.request.session.get('schedule', '')
        context['checkout_type'] = self.request.session.get('checkout_type', 'donation')
        context['occurrence'] = self.request.session.get('occurrence', 'onetime')
        context['quantity'] = self.request.session.get('quantity', 1)
        context['notes'] = self.request.session.get('notes', '')
        context['special_instructions'] = self.request.session.get('special_instructions', '')
        context['program'] = program
        context['amount_1'] = self.request.session.get('amount', '50')
        context['amount_2'] = 150
        context['amount_3'] = 600
        context['amount_4'] = 1000
        context['programs'] = Program.objects.all()

        return context

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()

        product = self.request.session.get('product', '')
        program = self.request.session.get('program', 'where-its-needed-most')
        schedule = self.request.session.get('schedule', '')
        shirt_size = self.request.session.get('shirt_size', '')

        if self.request.session.get('checkout_type') == 'purchase':
            initial["product"] = product
            initial["program"] = program
            initial['occurrence'] = 'onetime'
        elif self.request.session.get('checkout_type') == 'registration':
            initial["schedule"] = schedule
            initial["program"] = program
            initial["shirt_size"] = shirt_size
            initial['occurrence'] = 'onetime'
        elif 'rapid-response' in self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', ''):
            initial['program'] = Program.objects.get(name="College Support")
        elif 'brandsource-scholars' in self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', ''):
            initial['program'] = Program.objects.get(name="Scholarships")
        elif 'american-industries-scholarship' in self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', ''):
            initial['program'] = Program.objects.get(name="Scholarships")
        else:
            initial['program'] = program

        initial['first_name'] = self.request.session.get('first_name', '')
        initial['last_name'] = self.request.session.get('last_name', '')
        initial['email'] = self.request.session.get('email', '')
        initial['phone'] = self.request.session.get('phone', '')
        initial['billing_address'] = self.request.session.get('billing_address', '')
        initial['billing_address_ext'] = self.request.session.get('billing_address_ext', '')
        initial['billing_city_town'] = self.request.session.get('billing_city_town', '')
        initial['billing_state'] = self.request.session.get('billing_state', '')
        initial['billing_zipcode'] = self.request.session.get('billing_zipcode', '')
        initial['checkout_type'] = self.request.session.get('checkout_type', 'donation')
        initial['occurrence'] = self.request.session.get('occurrence', 'onetime')
        initial['amount'] = self.request.session.get('amount', "50")
        initial['quantity'] = self.request.session.get('quantity', "1")
        initial['company_matching'] = "no"
        initial['notes'] = self.request.session.get('notes', '')
        initial['utm_campaign'] = self.request.COOKIES.get('utm_campaign', '')
        initial['utm_content'] = self.request.COOKIES.get('utm_content', '')
        initial['utm_source'] = self.request.COOKIES.get('utm_source', '')
        initial['utm_medium'] = self.request.COOKIES.get('utm_medium', '')
        initial['utm_date'] = self.request.COOKIES.get('utm_date', '')
        initial['special_instructions'] = self.request.session.get('special_instructions', '')
        initial['conversion_url'] = self.request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER", '').split("?")[0]

        return initial

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            print('form valid')
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            print('form invalid mate')
            print(form.errors)
            messages.error(request, "An unexpected error has occurred.")
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        gateway = braintree_gateway(self.request)
        customer = find_or_create_customer(gateway, form)
        if form.cleaned_data['occurrence'] == 'monthly' or form.cleaned_data['occurrence'] == 'annually' or form.cleaned_data['occurrence'] == 'biannually':
            result = braintree_process_recurring_payment(self, form, gateway, customer)
            print(result)
        else:
            result = braintree_process_onetime_payment(self, form, gateway, customer)
            print(result)
        if result.is_success:            
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            html_content_internal = render_to_string('emails/donation_error.html', { 
                'message': result.message,
                'params': result.params,
                }
            )  

            subject, from_email, to = 'Donation Failure', 'Foster Love <info@togetherwerise.org>', "lh@togetherwerise.org"
            text_content = 'Payment Received'
            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
            msg.attach_alternative(html_content_internal, "text/html")
            msg.send()
            messages.error(self.request, result.message)
            print(result)
            return super().form_invalid(form)

def find_or_create_customer(gateway, form):

    first_name = form.cleaned_data["first_name"]
    last_name = form.cleaned_data["last_name"]
    email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
    phone = form.cleaned_data["phone"]
    group_type = form.cleaned_data["group_type"]
    billing_address = form.cleaned_data["billing_address"]
    billing_address_ext = form.cleaned_data["billing_address_ext"]
    billing_city_town = form.cleaned_data["billing_city_town"]
    billing_state = form.cleaned_data["billing_state"]
    billing_zipcode = form.cleaned_data["billing_zipcode"]

    try:
        customer = Customer.objects.get(email=email)
        customer = gateway.customer.find(customer.braintree_id)
        customer_id = customer.id
    except:
        try:
            customer = gateway.customer.find(customer.braintree_id)
            customer_id = customer.id
        except:
            result = gateway.customer.create({
                "first_name": first_name,
                "last_name": last_name,
                "phone": re.sub('[^0-9]', '', phone),
                "email": email,
            })
            if result.is_success:
                customer_id = result.customer.id
            else:
                customer_id = uuid.uuid4()

    values_to_update = {
        'first_name': first_name,
        'last_name': last_name,
        'phone': re.sub('[^0-9]', '', phone),
        'group_type': group_type,
        'billing_address': billing_address,
        'billing_address_ext': billing_address_ext,
        'billing_city_town': billing_city_town,
        'billing_state': billing_state,
        'billing_zipcode': billing_zipcode,
        'braintree_id': customer_id,
        'zoho_contact_id': create_or_update_zoho_contact(first_name, last_name, email, phone, group_type, billing_address, billing_address_ext, billing_city_town, billing_state, billing_zipcode)
    }

    customer, created = Customer.objects.update_or_create(
        email = email,
        defaults=values_to_update
    )
    customer.save()

    return customer
```